# Visual Studio 2012 missing ;

Tags: c++, identifier

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "Sala.h"
#include "EdicaoDisciplina.h"
#include "Semana.h"
#include "Aluno.h"
using namespace std;

class ActividadeLectiva{

private:
    EdicaoDisciplina disciplina;
    Semana semana;
    list <Sala> salas;
    int hora;
    string tipo;
    string descricao;
    list <Aluno> alunos;

public:
    ActividadeLectiva();
    ActividadeLectiva(EdicaoDisciplina disc, Semana semana, list <Sala> salas, int hora, string tipo, string descricao, list<Aluno> alunos);
    ActividadeLectiva(const ActividadeLectiva &e);
    ~ActividadeLectiva();

    EdicaoDisciplina getDisciplina() const;
    Semana getSemana() const;
    list <Sala> getSalas() const;
    int getHora() const;
    string getTipo() const;
    string getDescricao() const;
    list <Aluno> getAlunos() const;

    void setDisciplina(const EdicaoDisciplina &e);
    void setSemana(const Semana &s);
    void setSalas(list <Sala> salas);
    void setHora(int hora);
    void setTipo(string tipo);
    void setDescricao(string descricao);
    void setAlunos(list <Aluno> alunos);
};
```

It keeps giving me tons of error of missing ';' before the identifiers but I swear to god I can't figure where the problem is. Iam kind of tired but still I don't see any error. It will probably be something dumb but could you guys point me out to the right direction?

Comment: Check the .h files, especially for missing semicolons after class declarations.

Comment: Start comment stuff out until the error goes away. Then start putting stuff back in

Comment: You may have to provide what's inside Sala.h, EdicaoDisciplina.h, Semana.h and Aluno.h

Comment: We need to see the header files you're including.

Comment: Don't use "using namespace..." inside a header file. You'll run into problems sooner or later.

Comment: It becomes giving errors in the first attribute. And I checked all the other classes and not one has an error.

Comment: Please post the actual error messages.

Comment: It's all right now. I was entering in an infinite loop since one class had one attribute referencing other class who did the same. Rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be in one of these include files:

```
#include "Sala.h"
#include "EdicaoDisciplina.h"
#include "Semana.h"
#include "Aluno.h"
```

It is a good idea to create a .cpp for each .h that is empty asside from including the header so

**Sala.h.cpp**:

```
#include "Sala.h"
```

**EdicaoDisciplina.h.cpp**:

```
#include "EdicaoDisciplina.h"
```

**Semana.h**:

```
#include "Semana.h"
```

**Aluno.h**:

```
#include "Aluno.h"
```

and so on, repeating this for all include files in those include files, etc..

and then check to see if any of the .h.cpp produce a more useful error when you compile them

Comment: I commented all the class I psoted above and now it gives the same errors in those same classes. But the most annoying is that, those classes are all okay. What the hell is this?

Comment: @André I'm not clear on what you commented out - did you try compiling a .h.cpp for each header, and did they compile cleanly?  If not and it has other includes - keep creating .h.cpp until you find the problem one. (And keep them)